# How to use one variable for a parent and derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a a base class and a derived class. The derived class has some additional functionality, and the user can switch between which class they're accessing.

```
class BaseClass {
private:
    string valid_operations[2] = {"%", "#"};
};

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
private:
    string valid_operations[4] = {"!", "q", "%", "#"};
};
```

What I'm trying to do is instantiate a single object, and have the user be able to switch between these two objects interchangeably.

For example:

```
BaseClass obj;
string input;
while (true) {
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "switch")
      obj = DerivedClass();
    else
      obj.apply_action(input);
}
```

Is there a way to do this in C++? Also, is there a way I can declare `valid_operations` in `DerivedClass` to be `{"!", "q"} + BaseClass.valid_operations`?

Comment: Are you familiar with pointers, like `BaseClass *p`?

Comment: Why would the user need to switch objects? Well, I get that you want to switch *functionality* but why would the user care which object is being used? That seems more like a design decision you made and which might be worth revisiting.

Comment: Simplifying a situation to ask a focused question is good. In this case, however, I would be interested in knowing how much simplification went on. (Some solutions scale better than others.) Why is the base class treated as being on the same functional level as the derived class? Is there a plan to have more than one derived class? The example of a list of valid operations is succinct, but is there more going on? (Why have a derived class instead of just changing the list of valid operations as needed?)

Comment: That's a good question. This is for a project where the instructions were to make use of classes as part of the design, but I agree that it doesn't seem to make much sense given there isn't much else going on. The only "feature" the derived class adds is additional operations which can simply be toggled on/off using a flag on the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with an array variable, but if you opt for a vector, you could declare it in the base, and initialize in the protected constructor, like this:

```
class BaseClass {
private:
    std::vector<string> valid_operations;
protected:
    BaseClass(std::vector<string> vo) : valid_operations(vo) {}
public:
    void ShowValidOperations() {
        for (string op : valid_operations) {
            std::cout << op << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

class OptionOneDerived : public BaseClass {
public:
    OptionOneDerived() : BaseClass({"%", "#"}) {
    }
};

class OptionTwoDerived : public BaseClass {
public:
    OptionTwoDerived() : BaseClass({"!", "q", "%", "#"}) {
    }
};

int main() {
    BaseClass *b;
    OptionOneDerived a;
    b = &a;
    b->ShowValidOperations();
    OptionTwoDerived c;
    b = &c;
    b->ShowValidOperations();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that rather than using one derived class the example sets up a base that has no operations of its own, and relies on the subclass to provide the operation list in the constructor.

Also note that the implementation allocates derived classes in the `main` using automatic storage for expediency. An actual implementation would almost certainly use dynamic allocation with operators `new` and `delete` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the function `apply_action()` as a virtual function in the base class. You can then override the function in your derived class and make use of polymorphism.

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass(std::set<std::string> actions) : valid_operations(std::move(actions)) {}

    virtual void apply_action(std::string action)
    {
        if (IsValid(action))
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

protected:
    bool IsValid(const std::string& action)
    {
        return valid_operations.find(action) != std::end(valid_operations);
    }

private:
    std::set<std::string> valid_operations;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass(std::set<std::string> actions) : BaseClass(actions) {}

    virtual void apply_action(std::string action) override 
    {
        if (IsValid(action))
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

};
```

In your `main()` function or wherever you want to use these classes you can create instances like this:

```
BaseClass base({ "%", "#" });
DerivedClass derived({ "!", "q", "%", "#" });
```

Using one `BaseClass*` pointer you can switch to use either one of these objects. This is how polymorphism works: same name but different behaviour depending on the actual object used. Use a `BaseClass*` pointer and point to either `base` or `derived`.